# My Macbook Air isn't outputting the correct resolution

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, resolution

I bought a DELL P2416D with a 2560x1440 resolution but I didn't know that it wasn't compatible with OS X.

I use a mini Display Port to HDMI adapter.

Also the Mac detected the monitor as a TV and so used the YPbPr color format but I already fixed that issue by forcing the RGB color format and I would like to know if I can force a higher resolution or if you know a better solution to my problem.

Comment: Use a miniDP to full-size DP. The fewer translations it goes through, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I bought a Dell UltraSharp Monitor to use with a MacBook Pro.  It appears you may be using an older spec mDP to HDMI cable ([Probably HDMI 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.2))

> Version 1.2 HDMI 1.2 was released August 8, 2005 and added the option
>   of One Bit Audio, used on Super Audio CDs, at up to 8 channels. It
>   also added the availability of HDMI type A connectors for PC sources,
>   the ability for PC sources to implement only the sRGB color space
>   while retaining the option to implement the YCbCr color space, and
>   required HDMI 1.2 and later displays to allow low-voltage
>   sources.

That would explain why it showed up as a TV using YPbPr color format.

This particular monitor has a native DP interface - per Tetsujin, I would use that port instead of doing the conversion from mDP to HDMI.

If you want to go with HDMI, you will need an an mDP to HDMI 2.0 adapter and an HDMI 2.0 cable

[image]

**My suggestion** is to go native mDP to Display Port - it's much easier and you don't have to buy separate cables.

As for your MBA, every model from 2010 onwards supported the 2550x1400 resolution.  So unless you are using a 2009 model, you should be able to get the full resolution you are look for with either of these solutions.

Comment: can I use a HDMI 1.4 cable?

Comment: Absolutely.  I just recommended 2.0 (and above) because it's the current standard.  But if you have a 1.4, that should work just fine.  Make sure your adapter is at least 1.4 compliant or it won't work.  I still say, go mDP to DP for best results.  Cheapest method, too.

Comment: ok, I'll just buy the mDP to Display Port then.